# Raspberry Pi notorious problem = cannot find INSTALLED module

Tags: python-3, keyboard

I could not use module keyboard, I have check using `python3 -m pip list` to check the pip packages that I have installed and I saw that I have installed `keyboard 0.13.5`, however after I execute this code

```
import keyboard

shortcut = 'alt+x'
good = 'shift+a'
def on_triggered():
    print('hi')

keyboard.add_hotkey(shortcut,on_triggered)
keyboard.add_hotkey(good,on_triggered)

keyboard.wait('esc')
```

I still get this error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keyboard'`

Even if I have install the module with this code `python3 -m pip install keyboard` and this code `pip3 install keyboard`. Please help me I am using Raspberry Pi zero with python version 3.7.3

Btw this work on window 10 but it does not work on Raspberry Pi Zero.

I have check other question and follow their instruction by installing with python3 -m pip install, but nothing changed.

This is what it said after i install

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied: keyboard in /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.13.5)
```

Comment: The default python version is python2. How are you running your program. What's the name of your program file? Rename it to **ANYTHING** other than keyboard.py.

Comment: i dont have keyboard.py file the script name is test.py

Comment: Documentation says Linux requires sudo https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard

Comment: i did, i use `sudo python3 test.py`

Comment: If you repeat the installation steps with some module you don't have installed, like `numpy` or `pandas` (it can be anything, as long as it's not installed), then try to import it, do you get the same error? If not, than it's probably something wrong with the `keyboard` module.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue on my PC (running mint), I assume it's the same on a Pi running Raspbian or whatever.

As per this: https://stackabuse.com/guide-to-pythons-keyboard-module/ you need to install the keyboard module as root. So `sudo pip3 install keyboard`, and then run the python script with `sudo`.

That seems to work.